# Nintex Workflow

Tags: workflow, document-library

All,

I have attached an approval nintex workflow to a document library. I have 4 managers that need to approve the document that is uploaded and all have to approve.

What i need to accomplish is to have a column or another way of showing who has approved and who has not inside the library.

This is for SharePoint 2010.

is this possible?

Comment: Per the FAQ, questions about 3rd party products are out of scope for SPSE. Try Nintex Support. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be possible,

You add a column for the Managers who accepted the document. There you allow multiple persons.

In Nintex Workflow you do something like this:

Approval Element -> Approved -> Update List Element -> Add the approver to the column in the library.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, I used one of the nintex web parts that is available.